# How to load a UIImage from PhotoStream with UIImagePicker and Photo Framework under iOS 8.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

How do I use the new Photo Framework to get a UIImage from a given image URL which the UIImagePicker returns?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right...

You can open an UIImagePickerController like this:

```
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And after picking you get the UIImage from the pickers delegate like this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

The chosenImage will be your Image

**EDITED after complain**

Im sorry dude... the Key I have chosen is only available if you set  `picker.allowsEditing = true;` property on true...

So if you don't need the editing after you have chosen your image, use this one

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

instead of

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

I have just tried it, it will work...